# How does Doppler's effect work?

Tags: doppler-effect

If we wanted the period/frequency and the source has traveled for another period after travelling a period how would we do so? Since Doppler's formula only works for something that has traveled for exactly one period of time.

$$f' = f\left(\frac{v_s}{v_s \pm v_0}\right)$$

Shouldn't the formula be dependent on how far the listener is from the source?

Answer (score 1):

The Doppler formula should not depend on the distance between source/receiver, and the formula does require one period of travel. Think of (angular) frequency as rate of change of phase. A wave is

$ A(x, t) = \exp{ i \phi(x, t)} $

where the phase is normally written as:

$\phi(x, t) = 2\pi (ft-x/\lambda) = \omega t-kx$

so that:

$ \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t} = \omega = 2\pi f $,

now reconsider how a stationary observer hears a moving source, and likewise for a moving observer and a stationary source.